# Eclipse Juno not able to open xml

Tags: eclipse

i've been using eclise juno to develop in android.It's been a few weeks since i've used it last time.Now i'm trying to open an xml file in the xml editor,and i get 'Empty region!' do you know how i can fix this?Thank you for your time.

this is the stacktrace in case it helps you:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty region!
at javax.imageio.ImageReader.computeRegions(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.wbmp.WBMPImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.createBitmap(Bitmap_Delegate.java:96)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:233)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.loadIcon(CustomBar.java:165)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.loadIcon(CustomBar.java:144)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.FakeActionBar.<init>(FakeActionBar.java:37)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:270)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:322)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1638)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1389)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1163)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:674)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1081)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(FormEditor.java:607)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:362)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:129)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:95)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:300)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:859)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:839)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:319)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
```

Comment: I think you need to reinstall Eclipse. Looks like one of your icons is corrupted.

Comment: ....i thought so..thanks anyway!